# cassandra CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS not working

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Im using Cassandra 3.0.9 | CQL spec 3.4.0 and run this twice to test and it creates the table twice 
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS User WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
Its supposed to return error because is already created the second time I run it, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The keyspace 'User' is only created once if you execute your statement twice.

'IF NOT EXISTS' tells cassandra to ignore the create-request if the keyspace already exists. So you do not get an error here. If you omit this part you get the following error if the keyspace already exists.

```
AlreadyExists: Keyspace 'user' already exists
```

If this does not answer your question then may I ask where do you see that 'User' is created twice ? As a keyspace with the same name can only exist once.

Hope that helps, Christian

Comment: Yes it does help, I was confused because I read it like this IF NOT EXIST then create the keyspace, kinda rare for me. Reading the docs says what you said

Comment: I'm glad it helped. So if your question is answered with that I would like you to mark the answer.

Comment: I cant yet but as soon I can mark answers I will :)

Comment: Perhaps you have a high enough score to mark answers as correct now?